# What are $0 and $1 (dollar sign 0 and 1) in an awk script?

Tags: linux, awk

For example in [this `awk`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/opensource/Conceptual/ShellScripting/Howawk-ward/Howawk-ward.html) tutorial there are three examples:

1. `tolower($1) ~ /mary/ { print "CI Record: " $0; }`
2. `$0 !~ /Mary/ { print "Not Mary: " $0; }`
3. `$1 == "Mary" { print "Mary Record: " $0; }`

Comment: You should not even consider using awk until you can answer those questions easily for yourself as they are absolutely basic. It's like showing us a math problem and asking what "+" means. Get the book Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition By Arnold Robbins.

Comment: Agreed with @EdMorton . By the way, I am voting to reopen this question: its title triggers a lot of visits and a proper answer with a good explanation can give clarity on this topic.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Fields

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually example `# 2` is using a regex because of this syntax

```
/regex/
```

Which means in your example that if literal text `Mary` isn't found anywhere in whole line (`$0`) then execute awk code.

Whereas `$1 == "Mary"` is doing direct comparison between literal text `Mary` and field # 1 (`$1`).

Finally `tolower($1) ~ /mary/` is again using ignre-case regex match on field # 1 and this means if `$1` has text `mary` (ignore-case) then execute rest of the awk code.

Answer (score 48):

In awk, `$0` is the whole line of arguments, whereas `$1` is just the first argument in a list of arguments separated by spaces. So if I put "Mary had a little lamb" through awk, `$1` is "Mary", but `$0` is "Mary had a little lamb". The second line is trying to find the substring "Mary" in the whole line given to awk.

Answer (score 2):

From the description in your link (emphasis mine):

> The expression is generally either one of the fields or the result of
>   an operation on one of the fields. For example, the following AWK
>   filter rules show, **respectively**, how to compare the **first field** to
>   “mary” in a case-insensitive fashion, how to match **all records** that do
>   not contain “Mary”, and how to do an exact comparison of the **first
>   field** against “Mary”:

So breaking it down:

First one:

```
 how to compare the first field to “mary” in a case-insensitive fashion
```

Because it's comparing the first field, it uses `$1`

> how to match all records that do not contain “Mary”,

Since it's comparing all records, it uses `$0`

Third one

> and how to do an exact comparison of the first field against “Mary”:

Comparing first field again, so it's using `$1`.